# React validation form

Tags: reactjs

I send a request to the client register router, with axios, before that, I clear my variables using trim() toString() toLowerCase() functions, but it gives an error, not funciton, I couldn't find any validation package for react or something like that :(

```
 const [name, setName] = useState(null);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(null);
  const [emailRepeat, setEmailRepeat] = useState(null);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState(null);
  const [passwordRepeat, setPasswordRepeat] = useState(null);

  const sendRegisterRequest = async (e) => {
    const clearName = name.toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    const clearEmailRepeat = emailRepeat.toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    const clearEmail = email.toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    const clearPassword = password.trim().toLowerCase();
    const clearPasswordRepeat = passwordRepeat.toString().trim().toLowerCase();

   
    const passwordControll =
      password.length < 8 ||
      toast("En az 8 karakterli bir sayı ve harf girin !");

    const emailVerify = clearEmail === clearEmailRepeat;
    const passwordVerify = clearPassword === clearPasswordRepeat;

    if (emailVerify && passwordVerify && passwordControll) {
      const data = await axios("/api/auth/register", {
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          user: {
            name: clearName,
            email: clearEmail,
            password: clearPassword,
            isOnlie: true,
          },
        },
      })
        .then((res) => console.log("Başarlı işlem"))
        .catch((err) => toast(err));
    }
    return true;
  };
```

Comment: *"but it gives an error"* - ... And what is the error?  Which line produces the error?  What are the runtime values when the error occurs?  The error message is telling you what's wrong, you shouldn't be ignoring it.

Comment: toString() not function error

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that the browser console says, exactly, "toString() not function error".  Again, it's important to examine the *actual error message* and not *your interpretation of the error message*.  The answers below have probably resolved the problem.  But an important lesson here is to *read the error message*, not just skim it and assume it's not very important.

Answer (score 2):

Its probably because the default state of your fields is `null` but should be empty string:

```
 const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [emailRepeat, setEmailRepeat] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [passwordRepeat, setPasswordRepeat] = useState('');
```

`null` doesnt have any functions like `toString` attached. The default state of your fields should be a string with nothing in it, and not null.

React also does not like it if you pass `null` as the value to an `input` at any point as its not a valid value for a form field.

Comment: thank you the problem is fixed

Answer (score 2):

You can't perform the functions (toString, toLowerCase, trim etc) on a null value. You can initialize your state as follow:

```
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [emailRepeat, setEmailRepeat] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [passwordRepeat, setPasswordRepeat] = useState('');
```

You can perform the functions on an empty string. It won't give an error.

Hope this fix ur problems.

Comment: thank you the problem is fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
  import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { countries } from "countries-list";

function App() {
    const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }, reset, trigger } = useForm();
    const countriesList = Object.values(countries);

    //   useEffect(() => {
    //       trigger();
    //   }, [trigger]);

    //for update form use required property or onKeyUp
    //for regitraion useform reuired & oninvalid
    const submitHandler = (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        reset();
    };

    //for file
    const onChange = (event) => {
        const file = event.target.files;
        setFile(file);

        if (event.target.name === "file") {
            if (file.length === 0) {
                window.alert("Please select a product image");
                return false;
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
                if (file[i].type !== "image/png" && file[i].type !== "image/jpg" && file[i].type !== "image/jpeg") {
                    window.alert("File does not support. You must use .png or .jpg ");
                    return false;
                }
                if (file[i].size > 5000000) {
                    window.alert("Please upload a image smaller than 5 MB");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        const files = Array.from(event.target.files);
        setImagesPreview([]);
        setImages([]);

        files.forEach((file) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => {
                if (reader.readyState === 2) {
                    setImagesPreview((oldArray) => [...oldArray, reader.result]);
                    setImages((oldArray) => [...oldArray, reader.result]);
                }
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
    };

    //check password
    function check() {
        const password = document.querySelector('input[name=password]');
        const confirm = document.querySelector('input[name=confirm]');
        if (confirm.value === password.value) {
            confirm.setCustomValidity('');
        } else {
            confirm.setCustomValidity('Passwords do not match');
        }

        if (document.getElementById('password').value ==
            document.getElementById('confirm_password').value) {
            document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'green';
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'matching';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'red';
            document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'not matching';
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="container pt-5">
            <div className="row justify-content-sm-center pt-5">
                <div className="col-sm-6 shadow round pb-3">
                    <div className="wrapper my-5">
                        <h1 className="text-center pt-3 text-secondary">Example Form</h1>
                        <form className="shadow-lg" onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitHandler)} enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {/*-------Name--------- */}
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="name_field">Name</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    id="name_field"
                                    className={`form-control ${errors.name && "invalid"}`}
                                    {...register("name", { required: "Please enter the product name" })}
                                    onInvalid={() => { trigger("name"); }}
                                    // onKeyUp={() => {trigger("name");}}
                                    name="name"
                                    value={name}
                                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                                // required
                                />
                                {errors.name && (<small className="text-danger">{errors.name.message}</small>)}
                            </div>

                            {/*-------Email--------- */}
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="email_field">Email</label>
                                <input
                                    type="email"
                                    id="email_field"
                                    className={`form-control ${errors.email && "invalid"}`}
                                    {...register("email", {
                                        // required: "Please enter your Email ID",
                                        pattern: {
                                            value: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i,
                                            message: "Invalid Email ID",
                                        }
                                    })}
                                    oninvalid={() => { trigger("email"); }}
                                    name='email'
                                    value={email}
                                    onChange={onChange}
                                // pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$"
                                // required
                                />
                                {errors.email && (<small className="text-danger">{errors.email.message}</small>)}
                            </div>

                            {/*-------Password--------- */}
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="password_field">Password</label>
                                <input
                                    type="password"
                                    id="password_field"
                                    className={`form-control ${errors.password && "invalid"}`}
                                    {...register("password", {
                                        required: "Please enter the password",
                                        minLength: {
                                            value: 8,
                                            message: "Password should be at least 8 characters",
                                        },
                                        maxLength: {
                                            value: 50,
                                            message: "Password should be not more than 50 characters",
                                        }
                                    })}
                                    oninvalid={() => { trigger("password"); }}
                                    // onKeyUp={check}
                                    name='password'
                                    value={password}
                                    onChange={onChange}
                                // pattern=".{8,}"
                                // title="Eight or more characters"
                                // pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}"
                                // title="Must contain at least one  number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters"
                                // required
                                />
                                {errors.password && (<small className="text-danger">{errors.password.message}</small>)}
                            </div>

                            {/*-------Confirm Password--------- */}
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="confirm_password_field">Confirm Password</label>
                                <input
                                    type="password"
                                    id="confirm_password_field"
                                    className={`form-control ${errors.confirm_password && "invalid"}`}
                                    {...register("confirm_password", {
                                        required: "Please enter the password",
                                        validate: () => {
                                            if (watch('confirm_password') !== password) {
                                                return "Your passwords do not match";
                                            }
                                        },
                                        minLength: {
                                            value: 8,
                                            message: "Password should be at least 8 characters",
                                        },
                                        maxLength: {
                                            value: 50,
                                            message: "Password should be not more than 50 characters",
                                        }
                                    })}
                                    oninvalid={() => { trigger("confirm_password"); }}
                                    name='confirm_password'
                                    value={confirm_password}
                                    onChange={onChange}
                                // required
                                />
                                {errors.confirm_password && (<small className="text-danger">{errors.confirm_password.message}</small>)}
                            </div>

                            {/*-------Mobile--------- */}
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="mobile_field">Mobile Number</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    id="mobile_field"
                                    className={`form-control ${errors.mobile && "invalid"}`}
                                    {...register("mobile", {
                                        required: "Please enter your mobile number",
                                        pattern: {
                                            value: /^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$/,
                                            // for indian mobile no /^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\ -]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}|(\d[ -]?){10}\d$/
                                            message: "Invalid mobile no",
                                        }
                                    })}
                                    oninvalid={() => { trigger("mobile"); }}
                                    name='mobile'
                                    value={mobile}
                                    onChange={onChange}
                                // required
                                />
                                {errors.mobile && (<small className="text-danger">{errors.mobile.message}</small>)}
                            </div>

                            {/*-------Price--------- */}
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="price_field">Price</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    id="price_field"
                                    onWheel={(event) => event.currentTarget.blur()}
                                    name="price_field"
                                    className={`form-control ${errors.price && "invalid"}`}
                                    {...register("price", {
                                        required: "Please enter the product price.",
                                        min: {
                                            value: 1,
                                            message: "The minimum price should be not less than 1 ",
                                        },
                                        max: {
                                            value: 1000000,
                                            message: "The maximum price should be not more than 1000000",
                                        },
                                        pattern: {
                                            value: /^[0-9]*$/,
                                            message: "Only numbers are allowed",
                                        }
                                    })}
                                    onInvalid={() => { trigger("price"); }}
                                    value={original_price}
                                    onChange={(e) => setOriginal_price(e.target.value)}
                                    required
                                />
                                {errors.price && (<small className="text-danger">{errors.price.message}</small>)}
                            </div>

                            {/*-------Description--------- */}
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="description_field">Description</label>
                                <textarea
                                    name="description_field"
                                    id="description_field"
                                    className={`form-control ${errors.description && "invalid"}`}
                                    {...register("description", {
                                        minLength: {
                                            value: 20,
                                            message: "The minimum description length should be more than 20 characters",
                                        },
                                        maxLength: {
                                            value: 7000,
                                            message: "The maximum description length should be more than 7000 characters",
                                        }
                                    })}
                                    onInvalid={() => {
                                        trigger("description");
                                    }}
                                    rows="8"
                                    value={description}
                                    onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                                />
                                {errors.description && (<small className="text-danger">{errors.description.message}</small>)}
                            </div>

                            {/*-------Postal Code--------- */}
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="postal_code_field">Postal Code</label>
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    id="postal_code_field"
                                    className={`form-control ${errors.postal_code && "invalid"}`}
                                    {...register("postal_code", {
                                        pattern: {
                                            value: /^\d{3}\s?\d{3}$/,
                                            message: "Your Entered Zip Code Is Not Valid.",
                                        },
                                    })}
                                    oninvalid={() => { trigger("postal_code"); }}
                                    value={postalCode}
                                    onChange={(e) => setPostalCode(e.target.value)}
                                // pattern="([0-9]{6}|[0-9]{3}\s[0-9]{3})"
                                // required
                                />
                                {errors.postal_code && (<small className="text-danger">{errors.postal_code.message}</small>)}
                            </div>

                            {/*-------Select options--------- */}
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="category_field">Select Category</label>
                                <select
                                    id="category_field"
                                    className={`form-control ${errors.category && "invalid"}`}
                                    // required
                                    {...register("category", { required: "Please select one category of options" })}
                                    onInvalid={() => { trigger("category"); }}
                                    defaultValue={{ label: "Select Dept", value: 0 }}
                                    value={categoryName}
                                    onChange={(e) => setCategoryName(e.target.value)}
                                >
                                    <option value="">Please select a category...</option>
                                    {category.map((cat) => (
                                        <option key={cat.category} value={cat.category}>
                                            {cat.category}
                                        </option>
                                    ))}
                                </select>
                                {errors.category && (<small className="text-danger">{errors.category.message}</small>)}
                            </div>

                            {/*-------Date--------- */}
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="expired_field">Expiry Date</label>
                                <input
                                    type="date"
                                    id="expired_field"
                                    className="form-control"
                                    value={lastDate}
                                    onChange={(e) => setLastDate(e.target.value)}
                                    min={new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]}
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>

                            {/*-------Country--------- */}
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label htmlFor="country_field">Country</label>
                                <select
                                    id="country_field"
                                    className={`form-control ${errors.country && "invalid"}`}
                                    {...register("country", { required: "Please Select Country" })}
                                    oninvalid={() => { trigger("country"); }}

                                    value={country}
                                    onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}
                                    required
                                > {errors.country && (<small className="text-danger">{errors.country.message}</small>)}
                                    {countriesList.map((country) => (
                                        <option key={country.name} value={country.name}>
                                            {country.name}
                                        </option>
                                    ))}
                                </select>
                            </div>


                            {/*-------Search--------- */}
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label for="search">Search:</label>
                                <input
                                    type="search"
                                    id="search"
                                    name="search"
                                    pattern="[^'\x22]+"
                                    title="Invalid input"
                                    required
                                />
                            </div>

                            {/*-------Homepage--------- */}
                            <label for="website">Homepage:</label>
                            <input
                                type="url"
                                id="website"
                                name="website"
                                pattern="https?://.+"
                                title="Include http://"
                                required
                            />

                            {/*-------Images--------- */}
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label>Images</label>
                                <div className="custom-file">
                                    <input
                                        type="file"
                                        name="file"
                                        className="custom-file-input"
                                        id="customFile"
                                        onChange={onChange}
                                        multiple
                                        required
                                    />
                                    <label className="custom-file-label" htmlFor="customFile">Choose Images</label>
                                </div>

                                {imagesPreview.map((img) => (
                                    <img
                                        src={img}
                                        key={img}
                                        alt="Images Preview"
                                        className="mt-3 mr-2"
                                        width="55"
                                        height="52"
                                    />
                                ))}
                            </div>

                            <button type="submit" className="btn update-btn btn-block mt-4 mb-3" >Update</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;





    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>HTML Forms</h2>

    <form>
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input
        type="password"
        id="pwd"
        name="pwd"
        pattern=".{8,}"
        title="Eight or more characters"
        required
      /><br /><br />

      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input
        type="password"
        id="pwd"
        name="pwd"
        pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}"
        title="Must contain at least one  number and one uppercase and lowercase letter, and at least 8 or more characters"
        required
      /><br /><br />

      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        id="email"
        name="email"
        pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$"
        maxlength="10"
        minlength="8"
        required
      /><br /><br />

      <label for="search">Search:</label>
      <input
        type="search"
        id="search"
        name="search"
        pattern="[^'\x22]+"
        title="Invalid input"
        required
      /><br /><br />

      <label for="website">Homepage:</label>
      <input
        type="url"
        id="website"
        name="website"
        pattern="https?://.+"
        title="Include http://"
        required
      /><br /><br />

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    <p>
      If you click the "Submit" button, the form-data will be sent to a page
      called "/action_page.php".
    </p>
  </body>
</html>

//onkeyup='check();' for confirm password
/*
var check = function() {
  if (document.getElementById('password').value ==
    document.getElementById('confirm_password').value) {
    document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'green';
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'matching';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('message').style.color = 'red';
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'not matching';
  }
}
or

function onChange() {
  const password = document.querySelector('input[name=password]');
  const confirm = document.querySelector('input[name=confirm]');
  if (confirm.value === password.value) {
    confirm.setCustomValidity('');
  } else {
    confirm.setCustomValidity('Passwords do not match');
  }
}
*/


let mobile = /^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[ -]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$/g;
let email = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i;
```

Comment: You shouldn't be dumping your code as an answer without any explanation. This code doesn't even seem relevant to their problem.